# Output of an array is different whether used in a variable or printed

Tags: python

So I am trying to assign a string from an array to a variable and use it in a function. The string should be `"n02504458"`. Let me explain. Here is the original array:

```
('Predicted:', [
    (u'n02504458', u'African_elephant', 0.99588591), 
    (u'n01871265', u'tusker', 0.004068926),
    (u'n02504013', u'Indian_elephant', 4.499541e-05)
])
```

coming from the following line:

```
 decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0]
```

If I execute the following:

```
result = decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0]

code = result[0][0]
```

To just get `n02504458` and and print it out using `print(s)`, I get what I expect.
However when I try to pass it to a function as follow:

```
q = '"'
s = q + code + q
ids = synset_to_dfs_ids(s)
```

I will get an error. If I do the following however, I would not have any issues.

```
s = "n02504458"
ids = synset_to_dfs_ids(s)
```

I am very new to python and I do not really understand what is happening. Thanks for any help.

Comment: python 2 unicode/str mixup maybe?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get responses.

Comment: the question is probably OK if it's a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

In Python2, strings are, by default, simple ASCII - `<type 'str'>`. One way of forcing a string literal to be unicode instead is to preface the opening quote with the character `u` - `<type 'unicode'>`.
In general, you are better off to stick with one OR the other, and not mix them (eg. by using the `+` string concatenation operator).

To fix the code as you've written it, you can either:

- Drop the unicode prefix in your input strings; OR
- Make your quote-string `q` *also* unicode; OR
- In your concatenation step, convert your `code` variable from unicode into a "plain" string with `str(code)`, but note that this will fail if your inputs actually contain any non-ASCII characters.

Really, you want to know whether the `synset_to_dfs_ids(s)` function is expecting to get an *str* or a *unicode* string, and make sure it gets that.

The other thing to be aware of is that when you `print` out a variable, what you get is a *representation* of the object suitable for (usually) human viewing. It is not what the recipient "sees" when you pass the variable around.

So in this case, I really doubt that adding quotes around something that is already a (unicode) string is what you want to do.

Just pass `code` to `synset_to_dfs_ids()` as is, if the function can handle unicode, or convert `code` to the `<str>` *type* if necessary: `synset_to_dfs_ids(str(code))` (albeit with the proviso noted above).

(By the way, you wouldn't have this difficulty in Python3, where all strings are unicode by default. Unless you have a good reason for picking 2 over 3, I recommended just using Python3. Python2 is scheduled to reach end-of-life in 2020. In my opinion, 3 is a bit easier to learn, as well, as it smooths out some tricky irregularities.)

Comment: Thanks so much. I tried both suggestion, passing 'code' and 'str(code)', both work but they both pass u'n02504458' which is different from what I want and what is being printed, n02504458.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be adding too many quotes.

In your working example, you define a string `s_working = "n02504458"`. The variable `s_working` contains the characters `n02504458`.

In your "broken" example, you define a string `s_broken = '"' + code + '"'`. Assuming `code` is a string containing the characters `n02504458` , the variable `s_broken` contains the characters `"n02504458"`. You have explicitly added quotes to the variable!

Comment: I appreciate the help. What actually seems to be the issue is that what is being passed to the function is actually u'n02504458' which is different from what I want and what is being printed, n02504458.

Comment: You just have two different "flavors" of a string, one is a type `str` and the other type `unicode`. In many cases (though not all) they will work the same. There are many discussions out on the web. Here is one I like: [https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html]